# save a matrix (or a 2 dimensional array) in a sqlite db with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, matrix

I have a 2D array, M 390x420 with float values in it that I would like to save as a table in a sqlite db with python. the row number of the table should be 390, the column number 420.

*executemany* from sqlite is not optimal because then I would have to write ~ 420 of "?" , as far as I've understood.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you also tell me how to create the table with the 420 columns?                 `cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE " + str(matrix) + "(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,)")`

Comment: I wouldn't create a table with 420 columns in the first place. But you could use `range()` to get a bunch of numbers, then create column names from them.

Comment: Hm, good point about the 420 columns! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As CL recommended, not to use 420 columns. I would recommend an algorithmic approach to save much processing power. Here is an example, since the size is always 390x420, have a table with 10 columns, and 16380 rows. Referencing any point on this matrix can be done with a simple algorithm, and would be much more efficient. Remember, in sql, it is always better to have more rows than columns because of how the data is managed.